# Mock sub-function behaviour along with calling function

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I have the following code

```
def func2(col_a, col_b):
    return np.abs(col_b - col_a)

def func3(arr):
    return np.mean(arr)


def func1(df):
    col1 = df['col1'].to_numpy(copy=True)
    col2 = df['col2'].to_numpy(copy=True)
    col3 = df['col3'].to_numpy(copy=True)
    x1 = func2(col1, col3)
    x2 = func2(col2, col3)
    y1 = func3(x1)
    y2 = func3(x2) 
    # Performs computation with the variables about and returns a value
```

Over here I want to `mock` `func1`, `func2` and `func3` but rather than mocking the `return_value` of `func2` and `func3`, I want to `assert` that `func2` and `func3` are being called with the parameters I provide as `fixtures` using the mocked object of `func1`. This is my current code

```
@unittest.mock.patch(module.func1)
@unittest.mock.patch(module.func2)
@unittest.mock.patch(module.func3)
def test_func1(mock_func3, mock_func2, mock_func1, fixture_df, fixture_col1, fixture_col2, fixture_col3, fixture_func2_result1, fixture_func2_result2):
    mock_func1.return_value = 'place-holder'
    result = module.func1(fixture_df)

    assert mock_func2.call_count == 2
    assert mock_func3.call_count == 2
    
    expected_calls_func2 = [unittest.mock.call(fixture_col1, fixture_col3),
                            unittest.mock.call(fixture_col2, fixture_col3)]
    expected_calls_func3 = [unittest.mock.call(fixture_func2_result1),
                            unittest.mock.call(fixture_func2_result2)]
    mock_func2.mock_calls == expected_calls_func2
    mock_func3.mock_calls == expected_calls_func3
```

The code above does not work with an `assertionError` because the mock objects of `func2` and `func3` are not getting called within the patched `func1`. Removing the patch for `func1` solves the `assertionError` however I want to make this work using the patched `func1`. Is this possible?

Comment: When you are testing a function (in your case `func1`) you have to call the real function `func1` and not the mocked function. Because `func1` calls `func2` and `func3`, if you want you can mock `func2()` and `func3()` .